# ReactJS styles 'leaking' to other components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I have two components... a Navbar component, and an AboutPage component.

They are both in the same directory, 'App'

**App**

**-- Navbar** --> Navbar.css, Navbar.js

**-- AboutPage** --> Aboutpage.css, Aboutpage.js

So as you can see, they have two separate stylesheets.
In the JS pages the correct CSS file is being imported as well.

When I do a style like this for example:

*Navbar Component*

```
p { background: red }
```

^^ this style also applies to the p's in the Aboutpage. I even tried to give the P in Aboutpage its on id and style it that way and it still failed.

Comment: Dont write style of the tags themselves, write the style on your className or id.. the way you are writing this style will affect all p in the page.

Comment: so i have to give each element i want to style in react js an id or className in order to style it and not have it conflict with styles from other components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the expected behaviour.

No matter which file you specify a rule like `p { background: red }`, it's going to be applied to all DOM.
Specifying and id attribute to won't work either. The above rule is general enough to apply to all `<p>`s.

If you want to specify css files for each component, you should also create component specific css classes. Like the following example.

```
import React from 'react';
import './DottedBox.css';

const DottedBox = () => (
  <div className="DottedBox">
    <p className="DottedBox_content">Get started with CSS styling</p> 
  </div>
);

export default DottedBox;
```

and its css file:

```
.DottedBox {
  margin: 40px;
  border: 5px dotted pink;
}

.DottedBox_content {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you want different ways of defining css for React, this [resource](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822) adds 3 more ways of doing so, in addition to the above way.

Comment: thanks very much for your explaination. Jumping over from Angular to React gave me the expectation of component scoped styles :( Although I don't mind specifying.

Comment: No problem. There's still the React Styled-Components https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components, which can do almost the same

Answer (score 4):

You can also use css modules. They scope your CSS locally and are awesome

Answer (score 1):

Scoping styles to a component requires WebComponents which relies on several newer browser features, particularly shadowRoot "shadownDOM" which supports this separation directly.  These are most easily used with lit-element and/or Polymer 3.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need a global CSS which could affect another component even if we use module import, I didn't find anything to answer that in the official documentation, so my workaround is to use something like the following code in the component itself, and, it works fine  :)

```
        <style>
            {
            `
               @page {
                padding:0;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right:0;
            }
            @media print {
              @page {
                size: 80mm 21cm;
             }
            }
            `
            }
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

to prevent effect css class of a component to other components you can try to use **.module** extension on css file name.

-- Navbar --> Navbar.css, Navbar.js

**Rename to**

-- Navbar --> **Navbar.module.css**, Navbar.js

when you add **.module** extension on css file name, it will only effect a component you will import it.

If you want to check more information, this [resource](https://dev.to/eransakal/how-to-isolate-component-styles-in-react-using-css-modules-mkm) will help

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using custom-prefixed classes. and make use of `@at-root` and `#{&}`.

Let's say I want a class prefixed with my component's name "login" :

```scss
$prefix : login-;

.#{$prefix} {
    @at-root #{&}fun a {
        animation:blinkingText 1.2s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes blinkingText{
        0%{ color: #000000; }
        49%{ color: #000000; }
        60%{ color: white; }
        99%{ color:white; }
        100%{ color: #000000; }
    }
}
```

It will produce :

```scss
.login-fun a {
    animation: blinkingText 1.2s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText {
  0% { color: #000000; }
  49% { color: #000000; }
  60% { color: white; }
  99% { color: white; }
  100% { color: #000000; }
}
```

Then, let's assume that you will create your classes using string interpolation in you React component :

```
import "./style.scss";

const PREFIX = "login"

export BlinkingLink = () => (
    <div className={`${PREFIX}-fun`}>
       <a> Blink ! <a/>
    </div>
)
```

Like the author said [here](https://medium.com/web-developers-path/using-parent-selector-prefixes-in-sass-5adf22ff7078) :

> The `@at-root` will move the code block out of the parent selector and the `#{&}` will insert the parent selector after the specified prefix.